# Why my website not show php error when incorrect php code?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Why my website not show php error when incorrect php code ?

But it's still show 500 internal server error when incorrect php code.

How can i do for show php error when incorrect php code ?

i use this code on php.ini but not work

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: A 500 error isn't a PHP error. Perhaps there is no incorrect PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Display errors could be turned off in the php.ini or your Apache config file. You can turn it on in the script: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); You should see the same messages in the PHP error log.

[check detail here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)